# Find the PDF of a beta distribution given that $Y =-\log(X)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X \sim Be(3, 1)$.

(a) Find the probability density function (PDF) for $Y = −\log X$.

I have worked out that $X = 3x^2$ given the PDF of the beta distribution, but I am now confused at what to do. I set $Y = -\log(3x^2)$, and do I differentiate with the chain rule?

(b) Find $P(Y < E(Y ))$.

I have worked out $E(Y)$ but not sure as to how to get the probability

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hello! Do you know the theorem of change of probability variable? allows you to find one density in terms of the other

Comment: Writing $X=3x^2 $ is not correct. Instead use the notation $f_X(x)=3x^2$ for example.

Answer (score 2):

The probability density function (pdf) of $X$ is $$f_X(x)=\frac{x^{3-1}(1-x)^{0}}{\beta(3,1)}\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}=3 x^2\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$$.

The pdf of $Y$ is, by the transformation theorem, $$f_Y(y)=f_X(\mathrm e^{-y})\cdot |\frac{d}{dy}\mathrm e^{-y}|=3\mathrm e^{-2y}\mathrm e^{-y}\mathbf 1_{0<\mathrm e^{-y}<1}= 3e^{-3y}\,\mathbf 1_{0<y}$$
which is the pdf of an exponential random variable with parameter $3$.
Thus
$$Y\sim Exp(3)$$
and $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{1}{3}$.
Furthermore,
$$\mathbb{P}\left(Y<\tfrac{1}{3}\right)=F_Y\left(\tfrac{1}{3}\right)=1-\mathrm e^{-1},$$
where $F_Y(t)=(1-\mathrm e^{-3t})\,\mathbf 1_{0<t}$ is the cumulative distribution function of $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

***Graphical comment**,* illustrating transformation.
Images and objects have the same colors in the two histograms.

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rbeta(10^5, 3, 1)
y = -log(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 cutp = seq(0,1, by = .1); farb=rainbow(10)
 hist(x, prob=T, br= cutp, col=farb, main="BETA(3,1)")
  curve(dbeta(x, 3, 1), add=T, lwd=2)
 cutp2 = sort(-log(cutp)); cutp2[11]=max(y); farb2 = farb[10:1]
 hist(y, prob=T, br=cutp2, col=farb2, main="EXP(rate=3)")
  curve(dexp(x, 3), add=T, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]